# Google adsense responding the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Tags: adsense, adsense-api, google-advertising-id

I'm implementing google adsense first time on my website [myPleaks](https://www.mypleaks.com/survey/1/How-much-do-you-Rate-Modi-Government-tenure) .
Here I'm facing below mentioned error:-

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-4999083131788160&format=300x600&output=html&h=600&slotname=2819212735&adk=604957599&w=300&lmt=1463299293&flash=21.0.0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mypleaks.com%2Fnews%3Fid%3D2&wgl=1&dt=1463299292608&bpp=43&bdt=9534&fdt=60&idt=455&shv=r20160511&cbv=r20160512&saldr=aa&correlator=865300229149&frm=20&ga_vid=1280489623.1463299293&ga_sid=1463299293&ga_hid=45109378&ga_fc=0&pv=2&iag=3&icsg=2&nhd=1&dssz=2&mdo=0&mso=0&u_tz=330&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=900&u_w=1600&u_ah=860&u_aw=1600&u_cd=24&u_nplug=5&u_nmime=7&dff=helvetica%20neue&dfs=14&adx=2&ady=45&biw=1600&bih=775&eid=575144605%2C828064225%2C20040036&oid=3&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mypleaks.com%2Fhome&rx=0&eae=0&fc=80&pc=1&brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1600%2C0%2C1600%2C860%2C1600%2C775&vis=1&rsz=%7C%7Ca%7C&abl=CA&ppjl=d&pfx=0&fu=16&bc=1&ifi=1&xpc=3vCLOFZnnv&p=http%3A//www.mypleaks.com&dtd=558

Can anyone help me.?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm sure this issue is already solved. One of the possible reasons is that your ad unit is newly-created. Will need to wait for a while (hours perhaps) before you get the impressions.

Comment: I can verify that I've gotten this error specifically when the unit is newly created.

Answer (score 5):

It can mean:

- your ad is not approved yet or will be served soon
- the website is not yet approved to display ads
- the site has been disabled from serving ads

Check the status of your AdSense account and whether or not it's a host account. An "open" account doesn't necessarily mean it's been approved to show ads on a website. [Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/CBAi81YwPV0)

Comment: `there are too many ad codes on the page (max 3 allowed)` this is no longer true