# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () while trying to login into Instagram through Selenium and Python

Tags: ajax, python-2.7, selenium, instagram, webdriverwait

I've been in the process of making an instagram bot for a few days now and I'm having trouble logging into instagram with a headless selenium browser.

The script I made works perfectly fine when run on my laptop but when I try to run this on my digital ocean server, the browser will fill the login forms, then submit the form but nothing happens. I was able to print any console errors with this code:

```
for entry in self.browser.get_log('browser'):
        print(str(entry))
```

and this error comes up

> {u'source': u'network', u'message': u'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/ - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()', u'timestamp': 1546536937734, u'level': u'SEVERE'}

I am using the chromedriver for selenium and python2.7

I'm not completely sure why this is happening. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
{u'source': u'network', u'message': u'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/ - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()', u'timestamp': 1546536937734, u'level': u'SEVERE'}
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** as it failed to load the required resources through AJAX calls.

As per the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the [Instagram - Log in](https://www.instagram.com/) page it is pretty clear the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) contains [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled elements.

So while you invoke `get()` method before interacting with the elements on the particular you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be clickable* which will ensure that:

- The associated *JavaScript* and *AJAX Calls* have completed
- The desired elements are **enabled** and **visible** to recognize **`click`** events propogated through *Selenium*.

You can find a relevant discussion in [Google adsense responding the server responded with a status of 400 ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236229/google-adsense-responding-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-400)

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Filling in login forms in Instagram using selenium and webdriver (chrome) python OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938766/filling-in-login-forms-in-instagram-using-selenium-and-webdriver-chrome-python/49939562#49939562)